# Statically retrieving rules out of Laracasts\Validation classes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I have the following form validation class:

```
class EditItemsForm extends Laracasts\Validation\FormValidator
{
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|alpha'
    ];
}
```

I need to use the value in `$rules` to populate `Former::withRules()` so it can do it's thing.

I could try adding a static `getRules` method such that I can do `Former::withRules(EditItemsForm::getRules())` to get the protected value, but that requires creating a new instance of `EditItemsForm` which the parent `FromValidator` requires `Laracasts\Validation\FactoryInterface` as the first constructor argument.

Example:

```
public static function getRules()
{
    return with(new self(null))->rules;
}
```

Call me spoiled, but I have never had to deal with this before. So used to Laravel doing it's magical dependency injection in the background when input values are passed to a controller.

How can I get the value of `$rules` in this case without having to have an instance of `FactoryInterface`, or how do I dynamically create that instance to pass it in `getRules`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [IoC container](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#automatic-resolution) of Laravel to instantiate the `EditItemsForm` class. This will resolve the dependencies for you.

```
App::make('EditItemsForm');
```

A quote from Laravel docs

> The IoC container is powerful enough to resolve classes without any
>   configuration at all in many scenarios. For example:
>
> ```
> class FooBar {
>
>    public function __construct(Baz $baz)
>    {
>       $this->baz = $baz;
>    }
>
> }
>
> $fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
> ```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! The method `getRules` now contains `return \App::make('EditItemsForm')->rules;` which does the job.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.